# can anyone see any problems with this use case

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

I don't really understand the concept of use case diagrams but I have taken a crack at it. Can anyone see any problems with the following use case diagram:

[image]

Comment: gefei is correct use hashed line for include and if u explain the use case for this particular UML then i guess i can help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram

Answer (score 0):

lines of "include" relations are dashed and directed, see many many examples easily found by google.