# use case diagram the difference between extend and generalization

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm trying to figure out which connection I should use better because I don't quite understand the difference between these two connections.The connection of generalization is very clear to me on the example of actors, but is it possible to apply generalization on precedents? I will be very grateful to you for an explanation and examples.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72512652/extended-vs-generalization-in-use-case

Comment: You should probly rethink your "use cases" *Change email* is probably not a use case but merely a function. Use cases should represent the "major" user goals. Even *Edit your contact details* is questionable.

Comment: @GeertBellekens this is relative to registered users only. I want to differentiate the capabilities of users who are in the system and who are not in the system. So why is the possibility of changing contact details questionable?

Comment: @Smth_Unknown because I generally don't use applications (web or otherwise) in order to be able to edit my contact details. I use them to buy stuff, manage my invoices, consult my bankaccount. Those are my goals. Editing my contact details is never a goal. It's a *function* the app needs to provide in order to allow achieving the goals I stated. Do you see the difference? Not every function you system provides is a use case.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Oh, I think I understand it better now, thank you.  could I attach my small, but entire diagram to the question in order to receive comments and suggestions on it? I still have a poor understanding of the difference between extension and generalization, even after reviewing the questions above. On actors - it is clear. But in which case to use extension and generalization in use cases is still not very clear, unfortunately...

Comment: You should read Bittner/Spence if you want to understand UCs. Whatever is taught out there is generally rubbish (I'd say in more than 95%).