# Financial management use case diagram for dietary advisor application

Tags: uml, finance, use-case, use-case-diagram

This is use case diagram of financial management I have done but I am not sure if it's correct or completed:

[image]

I tried to add it as CRUD, but is this correct? And do I have to add more cases connected to Financial Management?

Answer (score 0):

The diagram looks syntactically ok, but it has some serious flaws that need to be addressed:

- A **use-case** must correspond to a set of behaviours with an observable result that is of value for the actors and that is independent of the internal structure of the system.  It corresponds generally to an actor's **goal**.  `Financial database` does not meet these requirements as it refers to the internal structure of the system and does not really describe a goal or a set of behaviours.
- An **actor** must be **external** to the system. The actor `Financial Management` that has the same name as the system under consideration which is also called `Financial Management` does not seem to comply with this rule.  Or the naming is unfortunate and should be disambiguated.
- The idea of the use-case is to help to understand what the actors can do with the system. Provide information, obtain information, update information and delete information seems very general in this regard.  It could apply to any information system. How can such a very general diagram help to understand what is to be designed/developed?

About the question whether CRUD is ok and `«extend»` the best way to model it, please refer to my other answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515246/3723423).  Keep in mind however that it is a level of decomposition that is not absolutely needed and  what exactly is the user may want to use the system for is much more important (e.g. manage bank accounts?  analyse financial transactions? Manage investments? but you have to find out what your app is doing - we cannot decide for you).