# UML Use case Specification for an Extended Use Case

Tags: uml, use-case, rup

I'm documentating a design, I have a doubt. The Use Case Specification RUP template have an extensión point section, and I was wondering if this section was meant to describe the extended use case or as I suppossed first, I have to make a specification of its own.

Someone please clarify this for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 due to this "please clarify" question is non-programing, shows no research effort and does not fit the on-topic question format: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [UML, include, extend relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331109/uml-include-extend-relationship)

Comment: Well, for this matter I did research for it, a lot, but no direct addressing was found. I need to clarify this matter specifically (I knew those concepts, but for me there was a room for doubt on this). I assumed If there was earlier questions about a related topic, this will be on topic. I'm sorry for that, it won't happen again (I readed the on-topic link).

Comment: please don't take my comment personally. There is just too many bad questions flooding the Stack Overflow site (read e.g. this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow and some of the linked questions). Quickly down voting or closing a question is one of the available defense moves. BTW: welcome to Stack Overflow :) and @Aleks is very good source of UML knowledge. Check his answers (their list is available from his profile page) and you may find many useful things you'd like to know..before asking

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't take it that way, I'm a member of some online communities and I try a lot to fit their rules because I like those the way they are and I have no intentions to mess up with it, and in this case it will be the same... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer to understand what is an extended UC.

[UML, include, extend relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331109/uml-include-extend-relationship/23335864#23335864)

***Extension point*** is defined in the **extended UC** and specifies how/when exactly the **extending UC** can be invoked. As a UC is typically described by scenarios and scenarios have steps, you usually describe the extension point as steps in which the extension can occur.

In the example I gave you, "Place order" is the **extended UC** and "Print Order" is the **extending UC**.

Let's suppose the following scenario of the "Place Order":
1. User fills the form
2. User confirms the input
3. System validates the input
4. If ok, System registers the Order
5. If ok, System displays the confirmation message

- Extension point might be defined for the step 5 (only successfull Order can be printed).
- Alternativelly it can be defined for the range of steps between 2-5 (Order might be in the DRAFT or COMPLETED state)

Another nice way to specify extension points is via activity diagram (if you want to avoid textual scenario descriptions).

Comment: So, what I understand is, extension point just describes where the **extended UC** connects with the **extending UC**, therefore, don't describe the **extending UC** itself, so, I have to do a use case specification documentation for the **extending UC** as well... Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, just like that. Extended UC doesn't know anything about the extending UC, and more - they are executing fully independent on each other.