# Software Engineering UML - the use of "include" and "extend"

Tags: include, uml, extend, use-case, requirements

I am currently modelling a system that I propose to implement

One feature or functionality is for the user to browse for music. But then they could also search for it - so does it mean that the `search for` use case `include` from `browse music` use case?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, my favorite ...

No, it does not include it. `Search music` is a single UC (it delivers a list of music titles). `Browse music` is no UC in contrast. It's simply an action you take (maybe at the end of `Search music`). A use case must deliver some added value. Just browsing is not really added value (ok, one can start arguing here - but ...).

Comment: Wouldn't it be the opposite --- the UC being "Browse music" with the capability of searching, sorting, filtering, ...? Or would those be two (three) different UCs?

Comment: @Peter The idea is to get the single points in the system that deliver added value. Not to model functionality how its connected.

Comment: Yes, one can start arguing.  But whether "browse" is legitimately a use case or not, I don't see any sort of include relationship.  Neither searching nor browsing includes the other: when you search you search, when you browse you browse.

Comment: @BobRodes I'm not sure whether Peter will be informed without the at-notification.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I believe the post owner is always notified when there's a comment.