# How can I draw a use case diagram for the report type?

Tags: modeling, use-case, use-case-diagram

How can I draw a use case diagram for the following?

Teachers are able to see **Exam reports** and administrators are able to see **Entire report** in The reports of my program.

Actors are able to Search Reports ,save and print their reports.

Comment: You can read about use case diagrams here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_use_case_diagram.htm
Ask here if you have a specific question.

Comment: This link will give you the answer. above one is not available anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link answer my Question.

[According to the Use case <<view reports>>, can we say that the diagram is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451820/according-to-the-use-case-view-reports-can-we-say-that-the-diagram-is-corre)

I need to add a constraint to describe that the admin can view all reports. This could simply be a textual note in curly brackets like { admin can view all reports} attached to the association between actor and UC.