# According to the Use case <<view reports>>, can we say that the diagram is correct?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

In my project, users (admins and education expert) are able to see dynamic reports. These reports are created in the Report File Manager.

Now, to draw up a use case **view reports**, Is the following diagram correct?

[image]

It should be noted that the admin are able to view all the reports and the education expert is able to view his self report. Will this change use case diagram?

//////According to the answers,I've drawn a new diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is your strange actor notation which I never have seen anywhere. An actor is shown as simple stickman.

You will need to add a constraint to describe that the admin can view all reports. This could simply be a textual note in curly brackets like `{ admin can view all reports}` attached to the association between actor and UC.

Besides that, think about collapsing all these single CRUD use cases into a single `Manage Report` since I guess that all are strongly connected. Else you're likely to be struck by the functional-descomposition-syndrome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This form of the actor represents <<Business Worker>>  type. Based on your response, I've drawn a new diagram.

Comment: The business worker is also shown as normal stickman. Just with the slanted dash (a hat??) in his egg-head xD. See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html Your new diagram looks fine now.

Comment: The question that comes up to me, is it necessary to distinguish a business actor from other actors? For example, this diagram can be used normal stickman?

Comment: Usually you don't need that separation. A simple actor is enough in almost all cases. You eventually want to distinguish between tech and business people sometimes. But usually the name and context are clear enough.