# Extending a view items usecase

Tags: uml, analysis, use-case

Suppose I have a use case with the name "View Items" that shows a list of items to the user. The user may optionally select a specific item to view its details and then back to the list again.

Should "View Item Details" extend "View Items" or they are stand-alone usecases?

Comment: IMO it should be a single use case, I usually make it as a standalone use case for that situations, it's a common scenario

Comment: There are various ways and all have pros and cons. This could be as simple as an alternate flow, or it could be two separate use cases or an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Extending definition [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html):

> Extend is a directed relationship that specifies **how and when** the
>   **behavior** defined in usually supplementary (optional) **extending use**
>   **case** can be **inserted** into the behavior defined in the **extended use**
>   **case**.

For example (in that reference):

[image]

> Registration use case is complete and meaningful on its own. It **could**
>   **be extended** with optional Get Help On Registration use case.

Meaning that, in `Registration` Use Case and in it's behavior, we **may need** to perform `Get Help On Registration` Use Case too.

It seems only a link, but it is **not just a link** to `Get Help On Registration` Use Case (we may need it to perform Registration).

For another example (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram)):
Suppose that we have `Answer the Question` Use Case and  `Research the Answer` Use Case. To perform `Answer the Question` Use Case we **may need to perform**  `Research the Answer` Use Case too. (And also this is not only a link)

[image]

For another example: 
Suppose that we have `Enroll in University` and `Perform Security Check` Use Cases. **To perform**  `Enroll in University` Use Case we **may need to perform**  `Perform Security Check` Use Case too.

**In Extend**:
A **behavior** extends another if it is in addition to, but not necessarily part of the **behavior**.

**Therefor**: In your example to perform `View Items` Use Case we do not need to perform `View Item Details` Use Case too. In other word, in the steps of `View Items` scenario, we do not need to perform (or optionally) `View Item Details` scenario. They are stand-alone Use Cases.

Answer (score 2):

I simply ask: does it add value? If yes, then just make it a stand alone use case. The use of `<<extend>>/<<include>>` usually indicates that someone is trying to do functional decomposition. I regard the introduction of these relations as bad move in UML which is likely sprung out of a technicians head than a business person. Added value can not really be sub-divided. Either it is, or is not.

"To add value, that is the question", and "There's something rotten in the state of UML".