# Use cases Extends and include

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have a not completed diagram of e-commerce order

I am not sure of the include and extend relatationship

Does this diagram is correct for the attached flow

[image]

Comment: For your now deleted question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#operator-precedence

Answer (score 2):

### About the relationships

An **`«extend»`** relationship `E - - -> B` means that E extends the behavior of B. B has a meaning on its own independently of its extensions, whereas E adds behavior in the context of B. E may be relevant on its own but it doesn't have to.   According to your diagram:

- `Register` extends `Login`.  This would mean that `Login` is an independent use-case that provides value even without any extension.  Conversely `Register` happens in the context of a `Login` and it could make sense on its own.   I'd understand that the `Login` allows also to `Register` new users.

An **`«include»`** relationship `B - - -> I` means that B behavior always includes I behavior. B needs I,  but I can is independent of B.   According to your diagram:

- `Authentication` includes `Login`.  So `Authentication` requires `Login`
- `Create order` includes `Authentication`.  In consequence, every time an order is created, an `authentication` is performed, which requires a `Login`.  Of course, this could make sense in a highly secured ordering system.  But for normal business system, this would mean a lot of mandatory logins.
- `Search product` includes `View product`.  I'd understand that when a user performs a product search, the search results can be viewed, and one could navigate directly to the product view.  But it's not clear which actor interacts with the search.

### About use-cases

Use-cases should have value for the user and correspond to some user goals: Placing an order is certainly a goal for some users.  But is the login really a user goal?  Isn't it rather some detailed steps required to fulfil other goals? While UML is agnostic about the interaction that a use-case may represent (example [argument in favor of a login use-case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/288481/209774)),  use-case gurus usually consider this as a bad practice (example [argument against login use-cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908056/3723423)).

Use-cases [should not be misused for functional decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419273/3723423).  I'd therefore advise a careful review of the search and view use-cases:  are these independent? Do they both provide value to the users?  Or is one just a functional detail of the other?