# what is the difference and purpose of Include and Exclude?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am a Final year student of Bachelors and making Final year project. My supervisor has given me the task to know about the purpose of Include and Exclude.
I have to use these in Use case Diagrams.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything .Anybody please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is about "exclude" ? Do you not confuse with "extend" for instance ?

Comment: See https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html and https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html

Comment: @bruno There was no uml tag when I've posted my comment

Comment: Duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram. The second answer is the best, I think.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl we are not sure it is about include and extend, this is only probable ;-)

Comment: @bruno Well, "exclude" is just nonsense. I closed it...