# use case diagram relationships

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am trying to draw a use case diagram for an event booking system, for the user who has the functions (use cases) Book Event and Cancel Booked Event, am I right to say that Cancel Booked Event includes Book Event as Cancel Booked Event can not take place without booking an event first? I have already read the following post [[What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram]) but am still unsure how it applies in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: You are not correct. `Cancel Booked Event` and `Book Event` should have no relation at all. They only way they are related is the fact that the post-condition of `Book Event`(event has been booked) is probably the pre-conditition for `Cancel Booked Event`

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks for the reply. I have read that post and some of the answers gave examples where user must Login in order to perform some function, some function -- <<includes>> --> login. May i know more about why this cant be applied to my scenario and how it differs?

Comment: The use case describes the behavior of a single session. If you walk into the office and you need to cancel a booked event, you don't have to book an event as well in that same session.

Comment: Just draw an association between Actor and Cancel and remove the include.